# Declare a let variable without assigning a value in Javascript, why that is?

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment, variable-declaration, event-delegation

I found this in Javascript.info : [enter link description here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Q6Aafx11IW6CnC8k?p=preview&preview).

Well it's a event delegation demonstration : a 9-cells table, when we click one of cells, the cell (`event.target`) changes its color into red and the cell we clicked just before will return to its original color.

And I'm wandering how is that possible declaring a `let` variable `selectedTd` without assigning a value ? (I made a comment in the js code in order to show you where the code confuses me). Thanks for your help.

```js
let table = document.getElementById('bagua-table');

    let selectedTd;

    table.onclick = function(event) {
      let target = event.target;

      while (target != this) {
        if (target.tagName == 'TD') {
          highlight(target);
          return;
        }
        target = target.parentNode;
      }
    }

    function highlight(node) {
      if (selectedTd) {  // what does the "selectedTd" representes while it doesn't even has a value ?  
        selectedTd.classList.remove('highlight');
      }
      selectedTd = node;
      selectedTd.classList.add('highlight');
    }
```

```css
#bagua-table th {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#bagua-table td {
  width: 150px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}

#bagua-table .nw {
  background: #999;
}

#bagua-table .n {
  background: #03f;
  color: #fff;
}

#bagua-table .ne {
  background: #ff6;
}

#bagua-table .w {
  background: #ff0;
}

#bagua-table .c {
  background: #60c;
  color: #fff;
}

#bagua-table .e {
  background: #09f;
  color: #fff;
}

#bagua-table .sw {
  background: #963;
  color: #fff;
}

#bagua-table .s {
  background: #f60;
  color: #fff;
}

#bagua-table .se {
  background: #0c3;
  color: #fff;
}

#bagua-table .highlight {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
  <table id="bagua-table">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3"><em>Bagua</em> Chart: Direction, Element, Color, Meaning</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="nw"><strong>Northwest</strong>
        <br>Metal
        <br>Silver
        <br>Elders
      </td>
      <td class="n"><strong>North</strong>
        <br>Water
        <br>Blue
        <br>Change
      </td>
      <td class="ne"><strong>Northeast</strong>
        <br>Earth
        <br>Yellow
        <br>Direction
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="w"><strong>West</strong>
        <br>Metal
        <br>Gold
        <br>Youth
      </td>
      <td class="c"><strong>Center</strong>
        <br>All
        <br>Purple
        <br>Harmony
      </td>
      <td class="e"><strong>East</strong>
        <br>Wood
        <br>Blue
        <br>Future
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sw"><strong>Southwest</strong>
        <br>Earth
        <br>Brown
        <br>Tranquility
      </td>
      <td class="s"><strong>South</strong>
        <br>Fire
        <br>Orange
        <br>Fame
      </td>
      <td class="se"><strong>Southeast</strong>
        <br>Wood
        <br>Green
        <br>Romance
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
```

Comment: It's the same as assigning `undefined` (which is falsy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first time when the code goes in the onclick function, its value is undefined (because no tds is selected yet), so it doesn't go in if statement and executes the next line after it which is:

```js
selectedTd = node;
```

So the next time when the user clicks on one of the tds, the value is set and is not undefined anymore, so it goes in if statement and removes the background color of the previous selectedTd.

Answer (score 1):

Let's trace the flow, At the start

1. **selectedId is undefined**
2. you click a cell and the function runs
3. It disregard the If condition to remove the highlight since there was no former selected cell
4. It highlights the cell and makes the **selectedId** carry the value of this node then the function exits
5. I click another cell now it runs the **If condition** removing the highlight of the current cell and repeats step 4

Answer (score 1):

```
 function highlight(node) {
      if (selectedTd) {  
        selectedTd.classList.remove('highlight');
      }
      selectedTd = node;
      selectedTd.classList.add('highlight');
    }
```

selectedTd starts off as undefined, this if statement checks to see if it's true or returns a value and if it is remove the 'hightlight' class.

```
 if (selectedTd) {  
        selectedTd.classList.remove('highlight');
      }
```

If that selectedTd returns undefined, false or has no value, here we set it equal to node, and add the 'highlight' class.

```
          selectedTd = node;
          selectedTd.classList.add('highlight');
```

we are passing `node` into the highlight function here, where if the target we choose is a td element then pass that to the highlight function and set selectedTd = to the target.

```
while (target != this) {
        if (target.tagName == 'TD') {
          highlight(target);
          return;
        }
```